# How do I Re-open a project in visual studio code

Tags: salesforcedx

I made a project in visual studio with SFDX: Create Project.  Everything was working fine.  Then I closed visual studio, because I'm on a desktop.  This was a big mistake.  In any event, when I turned on the desktop today and opened visual studio and opened the directory with my project with File>Open Folder, none of the usual command palette items are there.  This happened to me before and I followed this:
[how to authorize an org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/242581/no-option-for-sfdxauthorize-an-org-command-in-vs-code-command-palette)
But I didn't have a project at the time, I do now.

Also this:
[sfdc stuff](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IErmQAG)

Here are things I've tried.

My folder has the sfdx-project.json file
I opened it with open folder
I tried to open it with Open workspace from file, but it's not clear what file I'm supposed to open
I tried sfdx force:org:open -u [alias].
I then went right to the folder with the sfdx-project.json file and typed sfdx force:cofig:set defaultusername=[alias].

Still no usual command palette tools like deploy to org.  Also their readme.md wasn't great.
Their very first item was to go to the editor status bar and pick an org.  Here is my status bar:
[image: disappointing status bar]
No ability to pick org

Then I tried to authorize an org.  That's not an option in the command palette.  It didnt' matter. When I did sfdx force:org:list in the terminal, the org is there and it is connected.

So now what?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I opened the parent directory I initially picked to make a project.  It's important to open the directory that was made under this "parent" directory.  It's not smart enough to figure this out and so wasn't I until just now.  I'm going back to my microsoft excel now, which always works.